# Parsing key value pairs c#

Tags: c#, parsing, nini

I've been having issues attempting to parse key value pairs from a text file.  I've been scouring for libraries that can do what I'd like as I do not have the ability to create a class that can do this.

Here is the beginning of my file along with a portion of commented out text and key value pairs:

```
#!version:1.0.0.1

##File header "#!version:1.0.0.1" can not be edited or deleted, and must be placed in the first line.##

#######################################################################################
##                           Account1 Basic Settings                                 ##       
#######################################################################################

account.1.enable = 1
account.1.label = Front
account.1.display_name = Front
```

What I'm looking to do is grab these values, and be able to update them to within the file in the same location in the file that they are as these files need to remain human readable.

I've looked into Nini as this library seems to be able to do what I'd like, however the error I continue to have is based off of the line 1 of my file as it is not a key value pair.

```
Expected assignment operator (=) - Line: 1, Position: 19.
```

I read through the source of Nini, and it seems there is a way to condition the reader to use Mysqlstyle, which would use "#" as comments, but I'm unsure how to adjust it or if it is done automatically as it is completely over my head.

I understand that my files aren't legitimate ini files and there is probably a limitation within the Nini library as it searches for the section that the key value pairs are in.

The code I've attempted to use to parse and display this text to edit with Nini is as follows:

```
public void EditCFG(string file)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
    {
        IniConfigSource inifile = new IniConfigSource(file);
        account_1_display_name.Text = inifile.Configs[""].Get("account.1.display.name");
    }
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

### EDIT

Thanks to @rowland-shaw, I have found the solution:

```
    private IConfigSource source = null;

    public void EditCFG(string file)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
        {
            IniDocument inifile = new IniDocument(file, IniFileType.MysqlStyle);
            source = new IniConfigSource(inifile);
            account_1_display_name.Text = source.Configs["account"].Get("account.1.display_name");
        }
    }
```

However, this wasn't completely the answer.  I had to also implement sections within the file.  After testing my equipment that grabs these files with the updated text, everything was a success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125491/access-ini-file-from-documents-for-reading

Comment: This was what was in the code to begin with; this answer does not account for the condition MysqlStyle, nor does it account for the issue at hand.  Thank you for this, however I have found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [specify the `IniFileType`](http://nini.sourceforge.net/faq.php), i.e.:

```
IniConfigSource inifile = new IniConfigSource(file, IniFileType.MysqlStyle);
```

Long example:

```
IniDocument inifile = new IniDocument(file, IniFileType.MysqlStyle);
IniConfigSource source = new IniConfigSource(inifile);
```

Comment: Thank you Rowland!  That got me onto the right track!  I updated my original post with the updated code.  Please edit your answer to reflect my edit as it isn't exactly the solution as it has an error in it.  Once you do that, I will accept yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that is how the format is going to be (`key = value` and # for comments) in the file, you could do the following (c# pseudocode-ish, you can do the trivial stuff yourself):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;
foreach(string line in file)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

    // Remove extra spaces
    line = line.Trim();
    if(line[0] == '#') continue;

    string[] kvp = line.Split('=');
    dictionary[kvp[0].Trim()] = kvp[1].Trim(); // kvp[0] = key, kvp[1] = value
}
```

Then you can use the created dictionary like `account_1_display_name.Text = dictionary["account.1.display.name"];`

Comment: I have attempted to use write my own class with a dictionary similar to this, however I found that the going to save the file I was absolutely stuck as I could not then take all of the values from the dictionary and place them onto the same location of the file.

I did find my solution within the Nini library though.  Thank you for your time today!

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend my library [Nager.ConfigParser](https://github.com/nager/Nager.ConfigParser) you can easily obtain them over nuget.

Here the example for your configuration

```
var config = "#comment1\r\naccount.1.enable = 1\r\naccount.1.label = Front";

var configConvert = new ConfigConvert();
var item = configConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountCollection>(config);

public class AccountCollection
{
    [ConfigKey("account.")]
    [ConfigArray]
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account : ConfigArrayElement
{
    public int Enable { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [ConfigKey("display_name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```